# positioning the body element with canvas line

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with image. When user double clicks on it i am adding a horizontal line across the canvas and a `X` mark in-front of the line. This `X` mark is outside of the canvas. However somehow the TOP position of this X mark is not properly getting aligned with horizontal line, its off by few pixel

(please run the demo in full page mode to see the issue)

```js
$(function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};  
var img = new Image();

img.src = 'https://i.ndtvimg.com/i/2016-10/spud-boxer-best-dressed-dog_650x400_41476182056.jpg';
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
 canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
 canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
 }, false);


$("#canvas").dblclick(function (e) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#df4b26';
    ctx.moveTo(0, mousePos.y);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, mousePos.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    
    var top = e.clientY;
    var left = canvas.width + mousePos.rectLeft + 5; 

    $("body").append($("<span>x</span>").css({ top: top, left: left, position: 'absolute' }));
});

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: Math.floor(evt.clientX - rect.left),
            y: Math.floor(evt.clientY - rect.top),
            rectLeft: rect.left,
            rectTop: rect.top
        };
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" style="max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's well aligned but due to the `font-size` and the `line-height` the content-area (where the `x` belong) will be aligned not the `x`.

You can add `line-height:0` to fix this:

```js
$(function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};  
var img = new Image();

img.src = 'https://i.ndtvimg.com/i/2016-10/spud-boxer-best-dressed-dog_650x400_41476182056.jpg';
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
 canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
 canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
 }, false);


$("#canvas").dblclick(function (e) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#df4b26';
    ctx.moveTo(0, mousePos.y);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, mousePos.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    
    var top = e.clientY;
    var left = canvas.width + mousePos.rectLeft + 5; 

    $("body").append($("<span class='fix'>x</span>").css({ top: top, left: left, position: 'absolute' }));
});

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: Math.floor(evt.clientX - rect.left),
            y: Math.floor(evt.clientY - rect.top),
            rectLeft: rect.left,
            rectTop: rect.top
        };
    }

})
```

```css
.fix {
 line-height:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" style="max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
```